# Grid field not saving any data regardless of what I put in it

Tags: grid, ee3

Fresh install of EE 3.4.4

Created a channel and channel fields. Grid field has two subfields: one text input and one text area. When I publish a channel entry in this channel, all the other fields save just fine but this Grid field clears out and goes back to no rows when I save the channel entry. No errors, no nothing. It just doesn't save anything.

Comment: Same here. Also happens on EE 3.5.1. Haven't put my finger on what might be causing this.

Comment: Do you happen to be running PHP 5.3.x? I was on 5.3.5 (admittedly under the minimum requirements of 5.3.10) and trying out PHP 5.4.45 on MAMP made the Grid fields work normally.

Comment: Worked perfectly after upgrading. Thanks Zenbuman!

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer here was exactly what Zenbuman noted: it was the version of PHP. We upgraded to PHP5.4.5 on the server and no more problems.

Yay!